# Source operator doesn't work inside parenthesis in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, include, sh

I'd like to include a config file in my bash script with 2 conditions:

1. the config file name is constructed on-the-fly and stored in variable, and
2. in case if config file doesn't exist, the script should fail:

config.cfg:

```
 CONFIGURED=yes
```

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
$CFG=config.cfg

echo Source command doesn't work here:
[ -f $CFG ] && ( source $CFG ) || (echo $CFG doesnt exist; exit 127)
echo $CONFIGURED

echo ... but works here:
source $CFG
echo $CONFIGURED
```

What's wrong in [...] statement?

Comment: Why not use `if ... then ... else ... fi`?

Comment: This line: `$CFG=config.cfg` shouldn't have a dollar sign in it.

Comment: While your post is tagged "bash", the shebang line of your script is #!/bin/sh. POSIX shell (/bin/sh) does not have the "source" command. You have to use . instead. You may not notice this if /bin/sh is bash, but you will if you use dash instead.

Comment: FYI, only environment variables and built-in variables should be capitalized by convention.

Answer (score 7):

`( ... )` runs the commands in a separate subshell. If you want to run the commands in the same shell if possible then use `{ ... ; }` instead.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio! that's just what I need. [+]

Comment: ...though in this specific case there's no need for either `( ... )` or `{ ... ; }`